# Android custom vector scaling

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape

I am attempting to create a custom shape to use as the background for my menu drawer. The issue i'm experiencing is that i can't get the shape i want. At the moment i am creating the shape as an svg in Adobe Illustrator and then [converting](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) that into an XML drawable but it isn't having the desired effect. How can i get the vector drawable to scale depending on its parent (`match_parent`) and content (`wrap_content`)?

**menu_shape.xml** 
An issue i've picked up on this is that this shape isn't exactly responsive as it is essentially being squeezed to fit the viewport and thus behaves extremely different depending on the screen size.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:viewportWidth="597.28"
    android:viewportHeight="542.16"
    android:width="597.28dp"
    android:height="542.16dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M0.5 303.39V0.5H596.78V370.39S310.5 797.13 0.5 303.39Z"
        android:fillColor="#A92324"
        android:strokeColor="#231F20"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeMiterLimit="10" />
</vector>
```

**Current result:** 
[image]

**Desired result:** 
The desired result is essentially a massive circle that is offset to the right slightly 
[image]

Comment: @Sha-1 do you have SVG of the shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
        android:viewportWidth="597.28"
        android:viewportHeight="542.16"
        android:width="597.28dp"
        android:height="542.16dp">
  <path
          android:pathData="M0.5 302.39V0.5H596.7V374.39S310.5 501.13 0.5 303.39Z"
          android:fillColor="#A92324"
          android:strokeColor="#231F20"
          android:strokeWidth="1"
          android:strokeMiterLimit="10" />
</vector>
```

Comment: This gives me the shape i am after, however how would i go about increasing the height of the shape depending on the content inside the layout?

Comment: With vector drawable, android:width and android:height is only valid for API < 21 or if you use wrap_content for your image. So you can set the witdh and the heigh in your layout xml code and your vector drawable will be scaled

Comment: I've created a relative layout with the drawable as the background with `layout_width: match_parent` and `layout_height: wrap_content`. However the shape isn't adjusting according to it's content, almost as if the shape's width and height are permanently set (which they seem to be in the xml you provided). The RelativeLayout increases in height but the drawable background doesn't

Answer (score 0):

> Try shape xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle">

                <padding android:left="-100dp"
                    android:top="-100dp"
                    android:right="-100dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval">
                <solid
                    android:color="#712EF1" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```