# Custom background shape for dynamic content - propper scaling

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I have a question about whats the propper way to use custom backgrounds (shapes) inside android.
I have the following screen (made with adobe xd):

[image: Custom background for gridlayout]

The transparent white shape should be used as a background for a scrollview inside which a gridlayout is placed. Now I want the background to scale properly when the gridlayout is being populated and that means that just the height should change.
This is the desired looks after the gridlayout was populated:

[image]

First I tried it by simply setting the image as the background to the gridlayout, and this is the output:

[image]

The problem is obvious, I dont want the circle to change its radius.
Then I came up with the idea of dividing the background, I cut of the upper part of the background, put it in a imageview, and placed it along with the gridlayout inside a relative layout. This seems to work, at least on those devices that I tested. But I dont think that this is the way to go, because I would have to provide an image for every possible screen size (and what about rotation - yes, more custom images ...)

Is there an androish way doing this properly and in a more dynmaic way? I have also found this: [Android custom vector scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916710/android-custom-vector-scaling), but it seems that there is exactly the same problem that I have - scaling the background when the screen size changes

Comment: No time to write a full on answer but have a look at 9-patch images. You could use your original image and mark that only the bottom portion should stretch or shrink when the drawable resizes:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this using `MaterialShapeDrawable`.

First add the material components dependency to your gradle `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`

You can then start applying edge and corner treatments to the Material versions of components like `CardView` and `TextView`.

The code below applies the built in `TriangleEdgeTreatment` to a `MaterialTextView`. See image below for how this would look like on a device (not perfect but just an example of what can be achieved)

```
//In OnCreateView
val text = view.findViewById<MaterialTextView>(R.id.text)
val topEdge = TriangleEdgeTreatment(resources.getDimension(R.dimen.triangle_depth), true)
val shapeAppearance = ShapeAppearanceModel.builder()
shapeAppearance.setTopEdge(topEdge)

card.background = MaterialShapeDrawable(shape.build()).apply {
    setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this@MyFragment.context!!, R.color.colorPrimary))
    paintStyle = Paint.Style.FILL
}
```

[image]

You can override the `EdgeTreatment` class to create your own implementation of an edge.

```
class CurvedEdgeTreatment() : EdgeTreatment() {
    override fun getEdgePath(
        length: Float,
        center: Float,
        interpolation: Float,
        shapePath: ShapePath
    ) {
    //Your implementation
    }
}
```

This is how I would see you solving your issue. For more information about the `MaterialShapeDrawable` and what can be achieved you can check out this [link](https://blog.octo.com/en/android-materialshapedrawable/), it contains some more examples around corner and edge treatments and may be able to help with your specific scenario.

Here's an actual implementation does what you want it to:

```
class CurvedEdgeTreatment(
    private val diameter: Float,
    private val roundedCornerRadius: Float = 0f,
    private val horizontalOffset: Float = 0f,
    private val verticalOffset: Float = 0f
) : EdgeTreatment() {
    private val arcQuarter = 90f
    private val arcHalf = 180f
    private val angleUp = 270f
    private val angleLeft = 180f

    override fun getEdgePath(
        length: Float,
        center: Float,
        interpolation: Float,
        shapePath: ShapePath
    ) {
        val radius = diameter / 2f
        val roundedCornerOffset: Float = interpolation * roundedCornerRadius
        val middle: Float = center + horizontalOffset

        // The center offset of the cutout tweens between the vertical offset when attached, and the
        // cradleRadius as it becomes detached.
        val verticalOffset: Float =
            interpolation * verticalOffset + (1 - interpolation) * radius
        val verticalOffsetRatio = verticalOffset / radius
        if (verticalOffsetRatio >= 1.0f) {
            // Vertical offset is so high that there's no curve to draw in the edge, i.e., the fab is
            // actually above the edge so just draw a straight line.
            shapePath.lineTo(length, 0f)
            return  // Early exit.
        }

        // Calculate the path of the cutout by calculating the location of two adjacent circles. One
        // circle is for the rounded corner. If the rounded corner circle radius is 0 the corner will
        // not be rounded. The other circle is the cutout.
        // Calculate the X distance between the center of the two adjacent circles using pythagorean
        // theorem.
        val distanceBetweenCenters = radius + roundedCornerOffset
        val distanceBetweenCentersSquared =
            distanceBetweenCenters * distanceBetweenCenters
        val distanceY = verticalOffset + roundedCornerOffset
        val distanceX =
            sqrt(distanceBetweenCentersSquared - (distanceY * distanceY).toDouble()).toFloat()

        // Calculate the x position of the rounded corner circles.
        val leftRoundedCornerCircleX = middle - distanceX
        val rightRoundedCornerCircleX = middle + distanceX

        // Calculate the arc between the center of the two circles.
        val cornerRadiusArcLength =
            Math.toDegrees(atan(distanceX / distanceY.toDouble())).toFloat()
        val cutoutArcOffset: Float = arcQuarter - cornerRadiusArcLength

        // Draw the starting line up to the left rounded corner.
        shapePath.lineTo( /* x= */leftRoundedCornerCircleX, 0f)

        // Draw the arc for the left rounded corner circle. The bounding box is the area around the
        // circle's center which is at `(leftRoundedCornerCircleX, roundedCornerOffset)`.
        shapePath.addArc( /* left= */
            leftRoundedCornerCircleX - roundedCornerOffset, 0f,  /* right= */
            leftRoundedCornerCircleX + roundedCornerOffset,  /* bottom= */
            roundedCornerOffset * 2,  /* startAngle= */
            angleUp,  /* sweepAngle= */
            cornerRadiusArcLength
        )

        // Draw the cutout circle.
        shapePath.addArc( /* left= */
            middle - radius,  /* top= */
            -radius - verticalOffset,  /* right= */
            middle + radius,  /* bottom= */
            radius - verticalOffset,  /* startAngle= */
            angleLeft - cutoutArcOffset,  /* sweepAngle= */
            cutoutArcOffset * 2 - arcHalf
        )

        // Draw an arc for the right rounded corner circle. The bounding box is the area around the
        // circle's center which is at `(rightRoundedCornerCircleX, roundedCornerOffset)`.
        shapePath.addArc( /* left= */
            rightRoundedCornerCircleX - roundedCornerOffset, 0f,  /* right= */
            rightRoundedCornerCircleX + roundedCornerOffset,  /* bottom= */
            roundedCornerOffset * 2,  /* startAngle= */
            angleUp - cornerRadiusArcLength,  /* sweepAngle= */
            cornerRadiusArcLength
        )

        // Draw the ending line after the right rounded corner.
        shapePath.lineTo( /* x= */length, 0f)
    }
}
```

This implementation is mostly copied from the `BottomAppBarEdgeTreatment` code which can be found [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment.java), some minor changes made to make it more useful for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you, it seems a little bit cumbersome, but I will give it a shot :)